# I get a fatal error after attempting to install wp-ecommerce plugin, can not find any other support with same error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I attempted to install a wp-ecommerce plugin, it gave me this fatal error and now it only shows the fatal error message when I try to access my wp-admin.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class wpsc_gateways in /home4/stickdog/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-components/merchant-core-v2/classes/wpsc-gateways.php on line 6

If I can access my file manager and I just delete the plugin will it solve my problem? I would rather use the plugin but if it won't work its ok.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're probably trying to `include` / `require` the file multiple times. Check the `wpsc-gateways.php` files and remove those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a programming perspective it seems like the PHP class `wpsc_gateways` is being redeclared in the coding. But since this is a pre-packaged plug-in that seems odd. Perhaps sloppy coding on the part of the original author.  If you delete the plugin the problem will be solved.  But maybe the plug-in was installed twice by accident?  Look at the contents if your `/home4/stickdog/public_html/wp-content/plugins/` to see if that might have happened.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! I checked the wp-content/plugins and only saw one instance of ecommerce plugin. I was actually able to access my cpanel I didnt think I would be able to because the error message showed up when I tried to access the site url as well. I deleted the plugin, but would like to use it if possible. If I delete the wpsc-gateways.php before installation might it be possible? Or is that a required .php?